# How to remove an alarm on Android Wear 5.1.x?

Tags: alarm, clock, android-wear

How can I remove an alarm I set on android wear 5.1.x. On 4.4.x-5.0.x there was an option to remove an alarm but i can't find it on android wear 5.1.x.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. First, on the watch face **swipe from to the left 3 times**, until you are at the end (The *OK Google* screen). Then scroll down and there should be an option to disable the alarms.

[image]